# regex expression for messages

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Message is minimum of 6 letters or numbers, any length, and any amount of lines.

the regex that i'm currently using only allows me to have one line anything further than that i get an error.

```
/^.{6}/
```

EX:

Oppan gang-namseutayil
Kang-namseutayil

Naje-neun ttasaroun inkanjeo-gin yeoja
Keopi hanjanye yeoyureuraneun pumkyeok i-nneun yeoja
Bami omyeon shimjangi tteugeowojineun yeoja
Keureon banjeon i-nneun yeoja

Naneun sana-i
Naje-neun neomankeum ttasaroun geureon sana-i
Keopi shikgido jeone wonsyas ttaerineun sana-i
Bami omyeon shimjangi teojyeobeorineun sana-i
Keureon sana-i

Areumdawo sarangseureowo
Keurae neo hey keurae baro neo hey

Comment: Take out the `^`, which signifies the beginning of the string.

Comment: put your answer here i'm going to accept your answer

Comment: It's posted. Did it end up being the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take out the `^`, which signifies the beginning of a string.

That's why it won't match text on multiple lines, because the text on line 2-the end isn't at the beginning of the string.

Comment: /.{6,100}/ <--correct your post was correct, it's my expression that is wrong "/.{6}/", it only accepts up to 6 characters that's why it signals an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\w` token to delimit to a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore. Then use `{6,}` to specify 6 or more characters. Use the `m` flag for multiline

`/\w{6,}/m`